# Analyze AVI for audio with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, media-info

I'm new to using `ffmpeg`.  I have some AVI files that I believe should have audio, but I cannot get the audio to play with VLC.   I tried using `ffmpeg` to analyze the AVI files for audio.

```python
import subprocess

def has_audio(filename):
    result = subprocess.run(["ffprobe", "-v", "error", "-show_entries",
                             "format=nb_streams", "-of",
                             "default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1", filename],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return int(result.stdout) -1

print(has_audio('filename.avi'))
```

Below is the output for one of the AVI files.  The file looks to have audio, but maybe I'm reading the output incorrectly.  I also tried the code in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64248933/how-to-check-if-a-video-has-sound-in-python), which tells me the video has audio.

How can I ensure that this file has audio or not using either `ffmpeg` or another application?

```
avi @ 0x7fddac005140] non-interleaved AVI
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, avi, from 'filename.avi':
  Metadata:
    date            : 2010-06-29
  Duration: 00:00:06.83, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10607 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline) (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080, 9878 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn
  Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 32000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 512 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, null, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    date            : 2010-06-29
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 32000 Hz, mono, s16, 512 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 pcm_s16le
size=N/A time=00:00:05.99 bitrate=N/A speed=1.52e+03x       
video:0kB audio:375kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7fdd9b704080] n_samples: 192000
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7fdd9b704080] mean_volume: -44.3 dB
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7fdd9b704080] max_volume: -16.2 dB
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7fdd9b704080] histogram_16db: 3
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7fdd9b704080] histogram_17db: 0
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7fdd9b704080] histogram_18db: 9
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7fdd9b704080] histogram_19db: 9
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7fdd9b704080] histogram_20db: 15
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7fdd9b704080] histogram_21db: 16
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7fdd9b704080] histogram_22db: 12
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7fdd9b704080] histogram_23db: 25
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7fdd9b704080] histogram_24db: 19
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7fdd9b704080] histogram_25db: 25
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7fdd9b704080] histogram_26db: 22
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7fdd9b704080] histogram_27db: 13
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7fdd9b704080] histogram_28db: 17
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0x7fdd9b704080] histogram_29db: 13
```

Here is the output from `MediaInfo`

```
Bit rate: 12884197, Frame rate: 30.000, Format: JPEG
Duration (raw value): 6833
Duration (other values:
['6 s 833 ms',
 '6 s 833 ms',
 '6 s 833 ms',
 '00:00:06.833',
 '00:00:06:25',
 '00:00:06.833 (00:00:06:25)']
Track data:
{'alignment': 'Aligned',
 'bit_depth': 16,
 'bit_rate': 512000,
 'bit_rate_mode': 'CBR',
 'channel_s': 1,
 'codec_id': '1',
 'codec_id_url': 'http://www.microsoft.com/windows/',
 'commercial_name': 'PCM',
 'count': '285',
 'count_of_stream_of_this_kind': '1',
 'delay': 0,
 'delay__origin': 'Stream',
 'delay_relative_to_video': 0,
 'duration': 6000,
 'format': 'PCM',
 'format_settings': 'Little / Signed',
 'format_settings__endianness': 'Little',
 'format_settings__sign': 'Signed',
 'interleave__duration': 1139,
 'kind_of_stream': 'Audio',
 'other_alignment': ['Aligned on interleaves'],
 'other_bit_depth': ['16 bits'],
 'other_bit_rate': ['512 kb/s'],
 'other_bit_rate_mode': ['Constant'],
 'other_channel_s': ['1 channel'],
 'other_delay': ['00:00:00.000', '00:00:00.000'],
 'other_delay__origin': ['Raw stream'],
 'other_delay_relative_to_video': ['00:00:00.000', '00:00:00.000'],
 'other_duration': ['6 s 0 ms',
                    '6 s 0 ms',
                    '6 s 0 ms',
                    '00:00:06.000',
                    '00:00:06.000'],
 'other_format': ['PCM'],
 'other_interleave__duration': ['1139',
                                '1139  ms (34.17 video frames)',
                                '34.17'],
 'other_kind_of_stream': ['Audio'],
 'other_sampling_rate': ['32.0 kHz'],
 'other_stream_size': ['375 KiB (4%)',
                       '375 KiB',
                       '375 KiB',
                       '375 KiB',
                       '375.0 KiB',
                       '375 KiB (4%)'],
 'other_track_id': ['1'],
 'proportion_of_this_stream': '0.04238',
 'samples_count': '192000',
 'sampling_rate': 32000,
 'stream_identifier': '0',
 'stream_size': 384000,
 'streamorder': '1',
 'track_id': 1,
 'track_type': 'Audio'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -i filename.avi -c:v copy -c:a aac file_pcm_to_aac.mp4
```

This will keep the video as is, but encode the PCM WAV to m4a AAC.

If that doesn't play:

```
ffmpeg -i filename.avi -an -c:v copy file_video_only.mp4 && ffmpeg -i filename.avi -vn filename_audio_only.wav
```

Then see if it will play as a wav file by itself with `aplay`. If not, try opening it with `audacity` to see if it opens. If `audacity` cannot open it, try dumping it to raw, specifying the input type.

```
ffmpeg -f s16le -i filename_audio_only.wav -c:a pcm_s16le output.wav
```

Then try to import it from RAW, specifying it's **signed, 16-bit, little endian, 32000 Hz, mono** to `audacity`.

---

There could be something to `[avi @ 0x5617e27c4cc0] non-interleaved AVI`.
This says, "[framerate has to be divisable by the audio sample rate](https://superuser.com/a/1649175/788170)".

AviSynth may be able to [use DirectShow to target the audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55966809/ffmpeg-audio-stream-extraction-on-non-interleaved-avi-slow-compared-to-avisynt) specifically.

From the above post:

> Now if I "reencode" the file in another AVI:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i f.avi -c copy f2.avi
> ```
>
> I can extract the audio from f2.avi in milliseconds!

Conversion to an interleaved `.avi` is easiest to try first.

---

I've played around with it and I'm pretty sure the audio converts.  The clip's only half a second of bumped microphone, so I'm not positive. It needs tested on a longer file.

The source video, when properly de-muxed from that strange PCM track, plays properly at `305K` in an `mkv` container. That left the audio.  WAV files are large, so that makes sense. The variations of extracting ranged from **2.4mb to 3.0mb**... Without `-f sle16` leading the input `.avi` file, it would extract something around 400k, which is all wrong.

```
├── [ 2.4M]  audio_file.wav
├── [ 3.3M]  MOVI0000.avi
├── [ 305K]  MOVI0000.mkv
```

There's no difference between `-c copy` or `-c:a pcm_s16le`, the file comes out 2.4mb+ (PCM is not compressed, so unless you are changing channel, frequency or bit-rate, it's redundant.)

This will properly convert the video:

```
 ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i MOVI0000.avi -vf "format=yuv420p" -c:v libx264 -x264opts b-pyramid=normal -g 120 -preset veryslow -b:v 500K -maxrate:v 4M -bufsize 8M -rc-lookahead 60 -refs 3 -bf 2 -b_strategy 2 -subq 11 -mixed-refs 1 -8x8dct 1 -partitions all -direct-pred auto -nal-hrd vbr -aq-mode autovariance -aq-strength 1.1 -trellis 2 -c:a aac -ac 1 -b:a 128k MOVI0000.mkv
```

If the audio isn't converting properly, just replace `-c:a aac -ac 1 -b:a 128k` with `-an` to eliminate it.

Comment: Thanks for the commands.  The audio channel still does not play, even though `ffmpeg` and `MediaInfo` shows that the file has an audio channel.  There is no sound playing in this channel in either `VLC` or `audacity`

Comment: Try the RAW dump from the `avi`.  `ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 32000 -ac 1 -i filename.avi -vn output.raw`  If that doesn't work, if you don't mind sharing the file, I'll take a look at it for you.

Comment: This command `ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 32000 -ac 1 -i filename.avi -vn output.raw` throws this error `Unable to find a suitable output format for output.raw`

Comment: Oh, my fault, change `.raw` to `.wav`.  Try adding `-map 0:a`.

Comment: where does `-map 0:a` go?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex Before the `-vn`.  You could move all of it after `-i filename.avi` except for `-f s16le`. I added some to the answer.  Some good possibilities.  It seems the non-interleaving is a big deal, but doable.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.  I think that the audio track is filled with white noise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151431/discussion-between-jaycravens-and-life-is-complex).

Answer (score 1):

Your output shows that the file has audio :

```
  Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 32000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 512 kb/s
```

Comment: I thought this too, but it won't play for some reason in VLC.  I guess that is another issue.

Comment: Video that doesn't play with VLC is pretty rare. Try to analyze the audio stream's type using a utility such as MediaInfo. Are you on Windows / Linux / Mac?

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using a MAC.  Do you want me to post the output of `MediaInfo`?

Comment: The codec_id_url is Microsoft and its name is PCM - this is decidedly WAV audio. VLC has no problem playing WAV, so it seems that the audio either corrupted or just silent. Try to notch up the play audio volume as much as possible, but if it's still silent then this is the conclusion.